# RegExp which allow only one space in between words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to remove white spaces from just the beginning of the word, not after, and only a single space after the word.

Used RegExp:

```
var re = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)*$/);
```

Test Exapmle:

```
1) wordX[space] - Should be allowed 
2) [space] - Should not be allowed 
3) WrodX[space][space]wordX - Should be allowed 
4) WrodX[space][space][space]wordX - Should be allowed 
5) WrodX[space][space][space][space] - Should be not be allowed 
6) WrodX[space][space] - Allowed with only one space the moment another space is entered **should not be allowed**
```

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your question.

Comment: Allowed? I can answer the question, but the examples make no sense.

Comment: Yeh I know but I have to do something like this.

Comment: What language is this for?  Why not search for whitespace only: `/\s{2,}/`.  In Javascript, you'd call `str.replace(/\s{2,}/, " ")`.

Comment: Yes, turn around the logic and reject if you see a match on `/^ |[ ][ ]/`.

Comment: title didn't match your question so i give -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
^\s*\w+(\s?$|\s{2,}\w+)+
```

Test cases ("s added for clarity):

```
"word"         - allowed (match==true)
"word "        - allowed (match==true)
"word  word"   - allowed (match==true)
"word   word"  - allowed (match==true)
" "            - not allowed (match==false)
"word  "       - not allowed (match==false)
"word    "     - not allowed (match==false)
" word"        - allowed (match==true)
"  word"       - allowed (match==true)
"  word "      - allowed (match==true)
"  word  word" - allowed (match==true)
```

[**See demo here.**](http://fiddle.re/q9d76)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. BTW Its working fine but not working when [space]someword - giving false but it should be true.

Comment: Ok, didnt know about that rule, let me adapt. How many spaces before a word? Only one? Should allow more than one?

Comment: n number of spaces can be before a word.

Comment: any luck. I am stuck with this expression regExp.test("test sa"); returning false

Answer (score 1):

try to use code that i am giving you and implement with javascript, i hope it will for you fine 
HTML Code

```
<input type="test" class="name" />
```

Javascript Code:

```
$('.name').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/(\s{2,})|[^a-zA-Z']/g, ' '));
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/^\s*/, ''));
    });
```

This code does not allow more than one spaces between characters or words. Check here [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2HUV7/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var re = /\S\s?$/;
```

This matches a non-space followed by at most one space at the end of the string.

BTW, there's no need to use `new RegExp` when you're providing a regexp literal. That's only needed when converting a string to a RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
/^(\w+)(\s+)/
```

and your code:

```
result = inputString.replace(/^(\w+)(\s+)?/g, "$1");
```

Comment: but when i say only {word} it will return false.